# Edit dashboard's help tab

Tags: contextual-help

I wish to edit the text in the dashboard's help tab. I can add help to other pages, but I want to change the text in the grey box with links on the right-hand side of the help tab.

It is on the 'For more information:' section. I want to add links to my support page and not the WordPress support forum.

```
function my_contextual_help( $contextual_help, $screen_id, $screen ) {
    if ( 'product' == $screen->id ) {
        $contextual_help = '<h2>Products</h2>
                            <p>Products show the details of the items that we sell on the website. You can see a list of them on this page in reverse chronological order - the latest one we added is first.</p> 
                            <p>You can view/edit the details of each product by clicking on its name, or you can perform bulk actions using the dropdown menu and selecting multiple items.</p>';

    }
    return $contextual_help;
}

add_action( 'contextual_help', 'my_contextual_help', 10, 3 );
```

This adds the left tab 'Products' with help text in the middle, but it has no right section. How could I add this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Contextual_Help_to_Administration_Menus) in the Codex seems outdated.

Use the following code (see comments):

```
// Priority 5 allows the removal of default tabs and insertion of other plugin's tabs 
add_filter( 'contextual_help', 'wpse_77308_products_help', 5, 3 );

function wpse_77308_products_help( $old_help, $screen_id, $screen )
{
    // Not our screen, exit earlier
    // Adjust for your correct screen_id, see plugin recommendation bellow
    if( 'edit-magazine' != $screen_id )
        return;

    // Remove default tabs
    $screen->remove_help_tabs();

    // Add one help tab
    // For new ones: duplicate this, change id's and create custom callbacks
    $screen->add_help_tab( array(
        'id'      => 'products-help',
        'title'   => 'Products',
        'content' => '', // left empty on purpose, we use the callback bellow
        'callback' => 'wpse_77308_print_help'
    ));

    // This sets the sidebar, which is common for all tabs of this screen
    get_current_screen()->set_help_sidebar(
        '<p><strong>' . __('For more information:') . '</strong></p>' .
        '<p>' . __('<a href="http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/" title="WordPress StackExchange" target="_blank">WordPress Answers</a>') . '</p>' .
        '<p>' . __('<a href="http://wordpress.org/support/" target="_blank">Support Forums</a>') . '</p>'
    );

    return $old_help;
}


function wpse_77308_print_help()
{
    echo '
        <p>Products show the details of the items that we sell on the website. 
        You can see a list of them on this page in reverse chronological order 
        - the latest one we added is first.</p> 

        <p>You can view/edit the details of each product
        by clicking on its name, or you can perform bulk actions 
        using the dropdown menu and selecting multiple items.</p>
    ';
}
```

**Result:**

[image: cpt help tab]

---

To get the right `$screen_id`, use the plugin [Current Admin Info](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/current-admin-info), born from two great Stack contributors (kaiser and Stephen Harris).

> Displays info about the current admin screen and its globals,
>   contextual hooks, etc.
>
> The info appears in new tabs in the »Contextual Help«-panel in the
>   upper right corner of an admin screen.

Comment: Thanks for the more in depth code. However what I am looking for is to include the right section, such as the on in the dashboard help tab. It is called For more information:

Comment: @Keith, [add](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/77308/edit) detailed description (with screenshot, if possible) to the Question itself. *The better the Q, the better the Answer...*

Comment: sorry, I am not explaining it right for you. I have included a screenshot now. It is the section marked with the green arrow. This is the area I wish to edit.

Comment: @Keith, updated the Answer to include the sidebar. I really think it would be beneficial if you posted in your Question the full code you are using to add the help tab.