# Adding Help Tabs To Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, contextual-help

Using this well written post - tutorial [Edit dashboard's help tab](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77308/edit-dashboards-help-tab/) I have full control over all standard WordPress admin screens.

Can this be modified to add "Help" Tabs to custom post types?

Comment: Hi, thank you @Mayeenul. This is the method I've been currently using - and it works on wp 3.6, but I'm aware that contextual_help has been depreciated, and was looking for a way to implement the add_help_tab method and have it work on both the "custom_post_type" and "edit-custom_post_type" screens. I'm not sure how to mark this...

Comment: I just edited both the Q & A, not given the answer. :) The answer was given by [Nat](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/37870/nat). You can comment on the answer to inform him/her about your experiment.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code for solve your Problem.

```
function custom_help() {
    global $post_ID;
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if( isset($_GET['post_type']) ) $post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
    else $post_type = get_post_type( $post_ID );

    if( $post_type == 'listing' ) :

    $screen->add_help_tab( array(
        'id' => 'you_custom_id', // unique id for the tab
        'title' => 'Custom Help', // unique visible title for the tab
        'content' => '<h3>Help Title</h3><p>Help content</p>', //actual help text
    ));

    $screen->add_help_tab( array(
        'id' => 'you_custom_id_2', // unique id for the second tab
        'title' => 'Custom Help 2', // unique visible title for the second tab
        'content' => '<h3>Help Title 2</h3><p>Help content</p>', //actual help text
    ));

    endif;

}

add_action('admin_head', 'custom_help');
```

Answer (score 0):

The method of Adding Help Tabs described here [Edit dashboard's help tab](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77308/edit-dashboards-help-tab/) also works for custom posts types as long as the edit-CustomPostType function (list admin screen) occurs before the CustomPostType function (edit / add new admin screen). For custom post type taxonomies use edit-taxonomyName. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I actually happened to bump into this answer yesterday on this tutorial:

- [Complete Guide: Custom Post Types](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/complete-guide-custom-post-types/).

Just change "product" on line 2 to suite your needs.

The contextual help feature is a descending tab which can be seen in the top right of pages where available. Let’s take a look at how the contents can be changed.

```
function my_contextual_help( $contextual_help, $screen_id, $screen ) { 
    if ( 'product' == $screen->id ) {

        $contextual_help = '<h2>Products</h2>
        <p>Products show the details of the items that we sell on the website. You can see a list of them on this page in reverse chronological order - the latest one we added is first.</p> 
        <p>You can view/edit the details of each product by clicking on its name, or you can perform bulk actions using the dropdown menu and selecting multiple items.</p>';

    } elseif ( 'edit-product' == $screen->id ) {

        $contextual_help = '<h2>Editing products</h2>
        <p>This page allows you to view/modify product details. Please make sure to fill out the available boxes with the appropriate details (product image, price, brand) and <strong>not</strong> add these details to the product description.</p>';

    }
    return $contextual_help;
}
add_action( 'contextual_help', 'my_contextual_help', 10, 3 );
```

The codes above will generate dynamic help tabs based on the `screen->id`, this essential when you want to show help tab only in a particular admin page or in your case a CPT, just target the slug og the CPT.